# Android: How to allow orientations based on device

Tags: android, layout, orientation, device, screen-size

I am developing an Android application and I'd like to support all device sizes, from phones to full-size tablets. I'd like to restrict the application to only using portrait orientation on smaller devices and allow a different, more large-screen friendly UI to be used in landscape when the device is larger. So far, I am unable to find any way, let alone a graceful way, to restrict an activity to allowing orientations based on the device's screen size.

An example would be this: A smartphone running the app is only allowed to use the layout resources in layout-small and layout-normal, and is not allowed to use landscape at all. A larger, tablet device gets to use UIs that are more large-screen friendly, and is allowed to be used in both portrait and landscape, with unique UIs for each orientation.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To force an Activity to go into portrait mode you can set it in the Android Manifest but this way you are not able specify it for smaller screens, I believe thats not possible. Also you should be careful doing this because certain phone are made for landscape mode.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen

To provide alternative layouts for specific screen sizes you can do it by adding parameters in the folder name

```
/res/layout-small/main.xml
/res/layout-normal/main.xml
/res/layout-large/main.xml
/res/layout-xlarge/main.xml
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Answer (score 0):

You could try getting the screen size programmatically using something like:

```
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

Then allow/unallow based on if the screensize is between specific boundries?

Comment: display.getWidth() is deprecated. Use displayMetrics.widthPixels instead.